# write more efficently numpy and pandas code

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i have a DataFrame

```
a= pd.read_csv('period_table',index_col=0)
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
```

[image]

i want to add at my var Me only the integer value of a row and i do in this way

```
    Me = pd.Series(df.loc[s[0],'ipo_oso':'neg'])
    Me=Me.dropna()
    Me = [int(x) for x in np.array(Me)]
```

where df is my DataFrame, s[0] is an external variable like 'H'.
i have used a Series because i don't know how to remove NaN value. how can i write it with less code and efficently

Comment: post a textual representation of your `df`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) *then* [`tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html) :

```
Me = df.loc[s[0], "ipo_oso":"neg"].dropna().tolist()
```

Output :

```
print(Me)
#[1, -1]
```